# $\operatorname{Spec} k[w,x,y,z] / (wz-xy)$ is normal

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This post concerns about Exercise 5.4.I(c) in Vakil's FOAG:

> Show that $\operatorname{Spec} k[w,x,y,z] / (wz-xy)$ is a normal scheme, where $k$ has non-2 characteristic.

We know, from the previous part of the exercise, that

> $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1, \cdots, x_n] / (x_1^2 + \cdots + x_m^2)$ is normal with $n \geq m \geq 3$ and non-2 chracteristic.

After playing around with elementary equations, we have
$$wz-xy = \left( \frac{w+z}{2} \right)^2 + \left( i \frac{w-z}{2} \right)^2 + \left( \frac{x-y}{2} \right)^2 + \left( i \frac{x+y}{2} \right)^2$$
Hence,
$$\operatorname{Spec} k[w+z, i(w-z), x-y, i(x+y)] / (wz-xy) = \operatorname{Spec} k(i)[w,x,y,z] / (wz-xy)$$
is a normal scheme, but how can I conclude that $\operatorname{Spec} k[w,x,y,z] / (wz-xy)$ is normal? It is trivial if $i \in k$, but otherwise I don't se anyway to "remove" that $i$.

Comment: Hint: you can get something much more amenable to an application of 5.4.H(a) if you make a different change of variables.

Comment: What would such a change of variable look like? My intuition says that I should take $A=k[x,y,z]$ and express $wz-xy$ as $w^2 - f$ with $f$ a polynomial in $x,y,z$ only, which doesn't seem possible.

Comment: Why not? Try setting $w=(w'-z')$ and $z=(w'+z')$ (this transformation is invertible because 2 is). What do you get?

Comment: That makes sense now. I just get $wz-xy = w'^2 - (z'^2+xy)$, and $z'^2+xy$ is clearly irreducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To recap the discussion from the comments and take this off the unanswered list, the point is you can make a slightly different change of variables to get something more amenable to an application of exercise 5.4.H(a).

In particular, if you change variables by setting $w=(w'-z')$ and $z=(w'+z')$ (this is invertible because $2$ is), we get $w'^2-(z'^2+xy)$, and it is clear that $z'^2+xy$ is irreducible. Therefore we can apply the result of 5.4.H(a) to get that $\operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z,w]/(wz-xy)\cong \operatorname{Spec} k[x,y,z',w']/(w'^2-(z'^2+xy))$ is normal.

Comment: Nice answer. (I would personally prefer to observe that $z'^{2} + xy$ is irreducible by, say, Eisenstein, than to say it's clear. But maybe it is just obvious enough as is.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Sure, that's a good addition. (I said "clear" because the OP did in the comments.)

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yeh Eisenstein is certainly one way to do it, but you can also easily see this by directly checking if any factorization exists. Since $z'^2+xy$ has pure degree 2, any factor of it has pure degree 1. Any such factorization must then be of the form $(z'+\text{something with degree 1}) (z'+\text{something with degree 1})$