# Check $k[x,y,z,u]/(xy-zu)$ is normal or not

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> I want to check the ring $k[x,y,z,u]/(xy-zu)$, where $k$ is an algebraically closed field,  is [normal](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/037B) or not.

Is there any way to show this ? I tried to prove the localizations at primes of height 1 are DVRs, but I don't know how to proceed. I wonder now if it is normal.

Following the discussion in the comments. Let's denote $R=k[x,y,z,u]/(xy-zu)$, and let $R_x,R_y$ be the localizations of $R$. We show that $R_x\cap R_y=R$. The result of the question follows once we notice the fact that the intersection of normals is normal.

Suppose $f,g\in R$ such that $f/x^m=g/y^n$. Therefore $y^nf-x^mg\in (xy-zu)$ now we can do our computation in $k[x,y,z,u]$. There exsits $h\in k[x,y,z,u]$ such that $y^nf=x^mg+(xy-zu)h$. We assume $g$ has been written of the form that all terms are distinct monomials. Suppose $y^n\nmid g$. Then $g$ must contain some monomial which cannot be divided by $y^n$. We assume such monomial has the form $t=x^ay^bz^cu^d$ where $b<n$. WLOG, let's assume the coefficient of $t$(and all monomials invovled) are $1$ and $c\leq d$. Thus, if $n\leq b+c$, in $R$, we can write $t'$ (the image of $t$ in $R$) as $x^{a+c}y^{b+c}u^{d-c}$, so $y^n|t'$. If $n>b+c$, since $y^n|x^mg+(xy-zu)h$ and $x^mt=x^{m+a}y^bz^cu^d$, it must vanish in RHS. Therefore, $h$ must contain either $x^{a+m-1}y^{b-1}z^cu^d$ or $x^{a+m}y^bz^{c-1}u^{d-1}$ and their correposding remainders in such algorithm are $-x^{a+m-1}y^{b-1}z^{c+1}u^{d+1}$ and $-x^{a+m+1}y^{b+1}z^{c-1}u^{d-1}$ we notice the indicies change by $ 1$ for either $xy$ or $zu$. (Since $y^n\nmid \text{remainders}$) If some term in $g$ kills such remainders, we see that $g$ contains $x^ay^bz^cu^d,-x^{a-1}y^{b-1}z^{c+1}u^{d+1}$ or $x^ay^bz^cu^d,-x^{a+1}y^{b+1}z^{c-1}u^{d-1}$. View such monomials in $R$, we deduce that $g$ contains $x^{a+c}y^{b+c}u^{d-c},-x^{a+c}y^{b+c}u^{d-c}$ in both cases, and they cancel out in $g'\in R$. Otherwise, the above remainders must be killed inside $h$ by the term $zu$ or $xy$, which turns out some new remainder of the form $-x^{a+m-i}y^{b-i}z^{c+i}u^{d+i}$ or $-x^{a+m+i}y^{b+i}z^{c-i}u^{d-i}$. We repeat the above steps, if terms in $g$ kills such remainders, viewing in $R$ it turns out to cancel with $t'$ in $R$. And such steps obviously terminates by degree consideration. Therefore, we can prove in $R$, $y^n|g$. This completes the proof of the question.

Is there any mistake in my proof ? Does this work for the question? Thanks

Comment: Do you assume that the characteristic of $k$ is not $2$? This doesn't change the result, but it may make the proof easier.

Comment: @AlexWertheim Yes, let's assume $k$ to be an infinite field

Comment: @user879078 An infinite field can have characteristic $2$.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4342788 for at least two reasons: in the linked thread the question relies on another result, and the characteristic is assumed $\ne2$. The assumption is important in that method of proof, but the result holds without this constraint.